# Conditional export based on props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to apply a redShadowMediaStyle to Media if Media is handed a backgroundColour of "red". Does anyone know how I can do this please?

**React component that uses Media:**

```
<Media
  backgroundColour={"red"}
/>
```

**Media component:**

```
 import mediaStyle from "assets/jss/material-kit-pro-react/components/mediaStyle.jsx";
 import redShadowMediaStyle from "assets/jss/material-kit-pro-react/components/suited/redShadowMediaStyle.jsx";

class Media extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      backgroundColour
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {/* content */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ((props.backgroundColour === "red")
  ? withStyles(redShadowMediaStyle)(Media)
  : withStyles(mediaStyle)(Media));
```

I think the issue is that backgroundcolour within class Media is not accessible to the export default expression.

Comment: There is no instance of `Media` yet as of the export, so there are no props. This seems like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What makes you think you should make the export conditional on props?

Comment: It was just that the component that calls this and supplies the props is the one that will know if it should be 'red' style or not.

Answer (score 5):

You're pretty close, you just need to have an interstitial component so you can do logic based on the current value of the backgroundColour prop. Try something like:

```
export default function MediaWrapper({ backgroundColour }) {
    if (backgroundColour === "red") {
        return withStyles(redShadowMediaStyle)(Media)
    }
    return withStyles(mediaStyle)(Media));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure how to implement this. I've put what I ultimately did as a separate reply.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in the end: 
1) created a 'red' css class in mediaStyle (rather than what I originally had, which was a separate CSS file redShadowMediaStyle) 
2) Edited Media to have: 
if (props.backgroundColour == "red") return   
else return